# How to copy cell value to a specific cell in a new worksheet before double click?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that has 6 columns and 45 rows. In column B, named I.D., each cell has an unique 3 letter identifier. What I want to do is to create a VBA code that will allow me to double click a cell within column B and copy it to a specific cell in a new worksheet. I'm having trouble specifying the range and transferring the information to a new worksheet. My code so far is as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, cancel As Boolean)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B3:B45")) Is Nothing Then
    cancel = True
    Worksheets("Dashboard").Activate
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to activate. Directly copy the relevant cell. Here is an example

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B3:B45")) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Copy Worksheets("Analysis").Range("A1")
        cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I am copying to Cell A1 in the `Analysis`. Feel free to change it.

Comment: Thanks! If I can I just want to clarify something. I see that you are copying to the worksheet called "Dashboard", but I want to copy from "Dashboard" to a new sheet called "Analysis". So in order to do this can I just do a variation of what you have but add in the := Sheets("Analysis")?

Comment: Yes :) Also `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` should reside in `Dashboard` code area.